# Why is <p> so long when I add an outline?

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I'm making a website, and something is quite annoying... here's the code:

```css
.log {
      color: #FF00FC;
      font-family: Josefin Regular;
      font-size: 12.8pt;
      outline: 3.2px solid #ff00fc;
      padding: 6px;
      position: relative;
      top: 400px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: rotate(10deg);
      z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class='log'>>_</p>
```

For some reason, this the `<p>` is so long, it takes up more than the screen. How can I make the `outline:` smaller to fit my liking? I want it to be much less wide. Thanks, I hope you understand.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is this going to be for? A "programming" button or something?

Comment: No just a fake console type thing for a website I'm making. Btw I'm a noob :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `p` element gets displayed as block. If you set display to `inline-block` it should fix the issue:

```css
.log {
      color: #FF00FC;
      font-family: Josefin Regular;
      font-size: 12.8pt;
      outline: 3.2px solid #ff00fc;
      padding: 6px;
      position: relative;
      top: 400px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: rotate(10deg);
      z-index: 0;
      
      display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<p class='log'>>_</p>
```

Comment: Apparently 7 seconds is worth 2x the votes. I yield to the FGITW :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `7 seconds away  - Just as long as I stay` :)

Answer (score 5):

Change `display` to `inline-block`:

```css
.log {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FF00FC;
  font-family: Josefin Regular;
  font-size: 12.8pt;
  outline: 3.2px solid #ff00fc;
  padding: 6px;
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
  left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class='log'>>_</p>
```

By default, `display: block` is applied to `<p>` which causes it to span the entire width of its container when its `position` is `relative` or `static`.

Alternatively, if `.log`'s parent is `position: relative`, you can change it to `position: absolute` and you won't need to apply `display: inline-block`:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.log {
  color: #FF00FC;
  font-family: Josefin Regular;
  font-size: 12.8pt;
  outline: 3.2px solid #ff00fc;
  padding: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class='log'>>_</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `p` element is has a `display: block;` by default, which will take up as much width as is allowed in the flow. By adding `display: inline-block;` to your `.log` rule, this should be resolved.